# License for Amphion fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-licensing

I'm a volunteer webmaster with a non-profit organization. Our original web site designer specified the "Amphion" font for some elements. This font is freely available on dozens of web sites. Some members of the society's board are concerned that we may be using this font illegally, since we have not paid a license fee for it. I've tried to locate the original owner of this font on the web with no success. So my question is: Should we be paying a license fee to someone for permission to use this font, and if so, who?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, and your question is about a legal issue more than a design one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be available for free widely, but that does not necessarily mean that it's legally available for free.

There does not seem to be any information about the licence or author, so I would err in the side of caution and substitute it for a font you KNOW can be used legally, either a commercial version like [Almeria](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/fontsite/almeria?refby=pixilate) Or a similar free font like [Anglecia](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/anglecia-pro-display)